# Вытащить из переменной только цифры

Tags: python

Есть переменная 1, её значение тест 12.
`1 = "test 12"`
Нужно присвоить другой переменной значение переменной 1, но, только цифру 12. Как это реализовать?

Comment: `res = int("test 12".split()[1])`

Comment: 12 это число....

Answer (score 1):

Есть такой вариант:

```py
a = "test 12";
res = ''.join(filter(str.isnumeric, a))
print(res)
# 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с регулярными выражениями.

```py
>>> import re
>>> re.findall("\d+", "test12")
["12"]
```

Почему-то мало кто любит работать с `re`, но мне всегда кажется, что это элегантное решение. Естественно, не во всех случаях применимо.

Вариант с `isdigit` с посимвольным перебором:

```py
>>> t = ''      
>>> for i in "test12":
...   if i.isdigit(): t+=i 
...
>>> t
'12'
```